# Replace the G-Sheet column value, if the column value exceeds a threshold value, with the average of 'n' previous values in a Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to replace the value in column when it is above my threshold range, with the average of 'n' previous values in the column having consistent values. (Using any formula in G-Sheets itself)

Here is my G-Sheet is dynamically generating the values using an API.

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the above link of the g-sheet image, there are some values highlighted in black. These are the values exceeding my threshold of value "55".

I have tried Conditional Formatting. But, I couldn't replace the values in that case. All I need is a solution within the G-sheets itself.

Comment: Why the last X values? Your averages would not be comparable. I would suggest to use a running average of fixed N values.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @Lalith. Could you please provide an example sheet so that we can better understand the context of the issue? Also, how are you getting all this data? Are you using Google Apps Script to get it? Cheers

Comment: This is the sheet's screenshot:https://imgur.com/Dn3sb4F . Yes, I am using Google Apps Script and getting data using API request.

Comment: @LalithVeeraBhadra I have provided a possible solution, please let me know if that is what you need/expected. Cheers!

Comment: Thank-you!!!@carlesgg97. Your code working is great. Now, I am able to sort my data point as per mentioned threshold values. Thank-you very much once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following GAS code:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Fix values')
  .addItem('Run fixer', 'fixValues')
  .addToUi();
}

function fixValues() {
  var n = 5;
  var threshold = 55;
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] > threshold && i==0)
      values[i][0] = threshold;
    if (values[i][0] > threshold && i>0) {
      var startAvgIdx = (i-n >= 0) ? i-n : 0;
      var sum = 0;
      for (var j=startAvgIdx; j<i; ++j) sum += values[j][0];
      var avg = sum / (i-startAvgIdx);
      values[i][0] = avg;
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValues(values);
}
```

This will create a menu on top of your Sheets document with a button that runs the function. The function will run over the selected range. You can see an example of the results below:

[image: Script execution example]

There is just one left to consider: What if the initial value is already larger than the threshold? Should it be left as is, should it be set to the threshold...? In my code, I have created it to be set to the threshold in case that situation occurs, but feel free to change it (code after the `if (values[i][0] > threshold && i==0)` line).